# Access POST data in node using koa-body and koa-router

Tags: node.js, ajax, post, koa2

Making a ajax POST from a User Agent

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://mysub.domain.dev/myroute',

            headers: {
              'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
            },
            contentType: 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8',
            success: function(result) {
              successAction();
            },
            processData: false,
            data: myResult['myValue']
          });
```

With Koa2 on my server, how do I get the data myResult['myValue'] from the POST body?

```
const bodyParser = require('koa-body');

const router = new Router();
const body = bodyParser();


router.post('/myroute/', body, async (ctx, next) => {

const getMyValue = ctx.request.body.data.myValue;

}
```

I've tried various combinations. All are undefined or empty objects.

```
const getMyValue = ctx.request.body
```

Object{}

```
const getMyValue = ctx.request.body.data;
```

undefined

```
const getMyValue = ctx.request.body.myResult['myValue'];
```

undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things going on here.

First, you need to explicitly tell `koa-body` to look for multipart form data (it's off by default). So:

```
const koaBody = require('koa-body')

router.post('/myroute', koaBody({ multipart: true }),
  async (ctx, next) => {
    // ctx.request.body.fields: additional (non-file) fields
    // ctx.request.body.files: files (octet-stream) 
  })
```

Second, in the client you're probably going to want to set the `enctype` and explicitly set `contentType` to `false`. This seems counter-intuitive, but it stops jQuery from adding a `ContentType` header which will be missing a boundary string. Your request would look something like this:

```
$('#go').click(evt => {
  evt.preventDefault()

  const data = new FormData($('#uploadForm')[0])
  data.append('extra', 'fields if required')

  $.ajax({
    contentType: false,
    data,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    processData: false,
    success: result => $('#result').text(result),
    type: 'POST',
    url: '...'
  })
})
```

Note that the `FormData` in the example might not fit your use case, it was just a convenient demonstration. It's likely you can simply use `data: myresult['myValue']`, assuming that's a file.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.   I'll accept once I've had a chance to implement.

Comment: Turns out what I needed was to drop the line "body = bodyParser()" and add parenthesis to the body() in the router.  Also didn't need ajax for my use case.  I'll clarify in another answer.  Thank you for being so helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out ajax was unnecessary, so the client is simply...

```
 post('/myroute', {data: myResult[myValue] });
```

Then the koa-body is injected into the router without instancing it in page scope first. Note the parenthesis...

```
const bodyParser = require('koa-body');

const router = new Router();

router.post('/myroute/', bodyParser(), async (ctx, next) => {

const getMyValue = ctx.request.body.data;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kickaha: you still need to enclose the bodyParser() with multipart because by default multipart:false in koa-body, instead your line should read:

```
router.post('/myroute/', bodyParser({multipart:true}), async (ctx, next) => {
```